# Shrink font size of TextField on overflow - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I want the font size of TextField content to shrink when a specific width of TextField is reached. I've tried a few solutions such as calculating the text width using text span but I'm hoping for a more performant solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that will reproduce the same issue? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto_size_text package only works for regular Text widgets.

[auto_size_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text_field) on the other hand will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with FittedBox widget

```
FittedBox(
 fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
 child: Text(...)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
SizedBox(
    width: desiredWidth,
    height: desiredHeight,
    child: FittedBox(
        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: desiredWidth,
                    minHeight: desiredHeight,
                ),
                child: TextField(
                    ...
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

The inner `ConstrainedBox` isn't required, but, without it, when the `TextField` is empty, the `IntrinsicWidth` shrinks it, creating a very small target.

In my project, I noticed some small differences depending on what type of `BoxFit` I use, so you can adjust that depending on your needs.

Some drawbacks:

- There is no lower bound, so the text will continue to shrink beyond the point where it is readable
- It does not keep track of the scaling factor, so if you use this for two `TextField`s, their font sizes may be mismatched

Answer (score -1):

Best way is using the package auto size text

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Check :

```
AutoSizeText(
  'My Text',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
  minFontSize: 18,
  maxLines: 4,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```